# Kubernetes cronjob missed schedule

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-cronjob

There are around 50 cronjobs running in EKS cluster. I want to find out reason when Cronjob miss to schedule a job, It seems like a tedious process to check schedule, concurrency policy, active jobs, startingDeadlineSeconds. In spite of all these checks, sometimes It is still unclear. Could not find useful information from controller logs. Is there any straight forward way to find out reason for missed schedule from logs?

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-03-02T20:19:23Z"
  name: <name >
  namespace: <namespace>
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Allow
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
        spec:
          affinity:
            nodeAffinity:
              requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
                nodeSelectorTerms:
                - matchExpressions:
                  - key: <key>
                    operator: In
                    values:
                    - "true"
          containers:
            image: <image-name>
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            name: solution-info
            resources:
              limits:
                cpu: 300m
                memory: 300Mi
              requests:
                cpu: 300m
                memory: 300Mi
            terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
            terminationMessagePolicy: File
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
          securityContext: {}
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
          tolerations:
          - effect: NoSchedule
            key: assets
            operator: Equal
            value: "true"
  schedule: 0 */6 * * *
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 10
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  suspend: false
status:
  lastScheduleTime: "2021-03-10T12:00:00Z"
```

Comment: Which exactly controller logs have you checked?

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I have checked in kube-controller-manager logs of control plane

Answer (score 0):

I've done some digging and there are few point I would like to cover in this case:

1. Control Plane components use `klog` library for logging. `kube-controller-manager` can either log each level a into a separate file inside a given dir when used with the `--log-dir` flag or log everything into a single file if used with `--log-file` flag. Bear in mind that they are [mutually exclusive](https://github.com/kubernetes/klog/blob/ffd1719980cd6d9bf82490bb960765464e82c4ce/klog.go#L491) and make sure you are checking the right logs.
2. The CronJob Controller [runes every 10 sec](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/392bf0adef478175b9cf0226b02820eb1820f797/pkg/controller/cronjob/cronjob_controller.go#L95-L96):

---

```
 // Check things every 10 second. 
 go wait.Until(jm.syncAll, 10*time.Second, stopCh)
```

If it is too late and [misses a schedule](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/392bf0adef478175b9cf0226b02820eb1820f797/pkg/controller/cronjob/cronjob_controller.go#L268-L284) it will log it:

---

```
 scheduledTime := times[len(times)-1] 
 tooLate := false 
 if sj.Spec.StartingDeadlineSeconds != nil { 
    tooLate = scheduledTime.Add(time.Second * time.Duration(*sj.Spec.StartingDeadlineSeconds)).Before(now) 
 } 
 if tooLate { 
    glog.V(4).Infof("Missed starting window for %s", nameForLog) 
    recorder.Eventf(sj, v1.EventTypeWarning, "MissSchedule", "Missed scheduled time to start a job: %s", scheduledTime.Format(time.RFC1123Z)) 
    // TODO: Since we don't set LastScheduleTime when not scheduling, we are going to keep noticing 
    // the miss every cycle.  In order to avoid sending multiple events, and to avoid processing 
    // the sj again and again, we could set a Status.LastMissedTime when we notice a miss. 
    // Then, when we call getRecentUnmetScheduleTimes, we can take max(creationTimestamp, 
    // Status.LastScheduleTime, Status.LastMissedTime), and then so we won't generate 
    // and event the next time we process it, and also so the user looking at the status 
    // can see easily that there was a missed execution. 
    return 
 }
```

So grepping the logs for "Missed starting window" or similar would provide expected results.

3. It is also highly advised to know the [CronJob limitations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#cron-job-limitations):

> **Caution:** If `startingDeadlineSeconds` is set to a value less than 10 seconds, the CronJob may not be scheduled. This is because the
> CronJob controller checks things every 10 seconds.

More details and reasons behind possible missed schedules can be found in the linked docs.

Comment: I verified control plane logging is enabled for eks cluster and searched with "missed starting window"/"missed"/"starting" in log insights query selecting log group /aws/eks/<cluster name>/cluster in specific time frame but no luck.

Cronjob is scheduled to run every 6 hours and has concurrent policy allow. I see "type: 'Normal' reason: 'SawCompletedJob'" log from kube-manager-controller for a job. But I don't find logs for next schedule.

Comment: Could you share your `CronJob` yaml config by editing the question?

Comment: Your `yaml` config looks valid. In that case, I suggest going a step forward and use 3rd party tools in order to monitor and debug your CronJobs. [Cronitor](https://cronitor.io/cron-job-monitoring?utm_source=crontabguru&utm_campaign=cron_failures) can be used for that.